# error in response in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to sign up with API "http://chattymac.herokuapp.com/v1/account/register" using retrofit in android. whenever a new user sign up we get response as html string "successfully registered" but when an existing user registers we get response in json format and app crashes giving NULLPointerException. My code is given below:

```
    public interface APIService {


@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Basic Z2VldGFuamFsaTpnZWV0YW5qYWxp"})
@POST("account/register")
Call<ResponseBody> createUser(@Body User user);
```

}

```
    public class User {
private String email;
private String password;

public User(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

}

```
    private void userSignUp() {
    //defining a progress dialog to show while signing up
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing Up...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String email = signUpEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = signUpPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //building retrofit object
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //Defining retrofit api service
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    //Defining the user object as we need to pass it with the call
    User user = new User(email, password);

    //defining the call
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.createUser(user);

    //calling the api
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //hiding progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                 responseMessage = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //displaying the message from the response as toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Since I am new to android, If anyone can help me out how to get both string and json response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if the response is successful first, by using response.isSuccessful()?

Comment: Yeah i have tried it too. the response is successful at first and gives a toast message "registered successfully" but when an existing user sign up, the app didn't crash but i don't receive any toast message.